# How to append new content in htmlService without call x time the back (gs code)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here the situation, I try to make a logging window on my spreadsheet. 
first, I try to with append on `createHtmlOutput()`, but I figure out after `showSideBar()`, it was impossible to append new content.

here exemple : 
[image]

So I try in another way.

here server side  :

```
   var logs = new Array();
//create html output from sidebar.html
function showSidebar() {
var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("sidebar");
//  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('output',output);
//  output.append("text");
    output.setTitle("test");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(output);
}

// Function to append new log
function addLog1(text) {
Logger.log("call");
Logger.log(logs);
//logs.push(text);
//  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('arr', logs);
 PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('arr', text);
}

function log1() {
 addLog1("coucou ");
}

function log2() {
Logger.log("ici");
 Utilities.sleep(2000);
 addLog1("coucou1");
}

function log3() {
Logger.log("ici");
 Utilities.sleep(2000);
 addLog1("coucou2");
}

function log4() {
Logger.log("ici");
 Utilities.sleep(2000);
 addLog1("coucou3");
}

function log5() {
Logger.log("ici");
 Utilities.sleep(2000);
 addLog1("coucou5");
}

//return log (i try with send just one string or an array of logs)
function actionOne() {
var res = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('arr');
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('arr', "");
  return res;
}

function test(){
showSidebar();
  log1();
  log2();
  log3();
  log4();
  log5();
}
```

Here client side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="logs"></div>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    setInterval(function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callActionTwo).actionOne();}, 500);
});
    var element = document.getElementById("logs");
    function callActionTwo(dat){
    if(dat){
//         var para = document.createElement("br");
//         para.innerHTML = dat[i] + "<br>";
//         document.getElementById("logs").appendChild(para);
            element.innerHTML += dat+ "<br>";
            }


    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem with this solution I call to many times PropertiesService and google put a limit on it.

If you have any suggestion I will be glad to ear  it
thank you

**EDIT**
After Anton'sanswer I change like this :

```
 //getProperty return an array of logs
    function actionOne() {
      var res = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('arr'));
      Logger.log("res " + res)
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('arr', "");
      logs = [];
      return res;
    }
```

But despite the clear of PropertiesService and array logs. I still have redundancy in my log
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide clarification of how do you need the log to appear. How do you need it to get saved because if you want the log of a single execution you could use Logger.getLog() and then print it.

Comment: I  want to build a manual log process and print it in the sidebar ( like screen). so i  pass a string that i  will format with argument and this string have to be display on the sidebar.

Comment: And do you want it to disappear after each execution or do you want the Log to stay? I asked that for the redundancy you are talking about, if you want to show the log each time, the log will have to clear out, if not you will have it like you do now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether your question is about PropertiesService limitations or the number of server calls.  Calling PropertiesService every 500 milliseconds is indeed overkill. 
If I understand your other question correctly, it's about avoiding multiple client-server calls to fetch data. Why not store all data in as a single key-value pair?

```
//write data to storage
var data = {
     log1: "data1",
     log2: "data2",
     log3: "data3"
};
var dataAsString = JSON.stringify(data);
var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
props.setProperty("data", data);

//Parse data
var data;
var dataAsString = props.getProperty("data");
try {
   data = JSON.parse(dataAsString);
} catch(e) {    
   data = {}; 
}

return data;
```

You can then iterate over properties of the data object on the client-side and append content to HTML tags.

Also, what's the point of sleeping when writing key-value pairs to the storage?

```
function log2() {
Logger.log("ici");
 Utilities.sleep(2000);
 addLog1("coucou1");
}
```

This only makes the script run slow.

Comment: Thx you for your answer, but I still need to call getProperty to check if there is new log in data? and I need to clear data  to not rewrite the same log in the client side?  .the sleep is here only to simulated a very big script. I will implement this log function into a script with like 30 files and more than 3000 lines.

Comment: @RaphaelObadia I don't see what might prevent you from doing all of the above. If you need to call this service every 500 milliseconds, I don't think there's a workaround

Comment: I have changed with array logs and call Properties service every 3000ms instead of 500. But I have a small problem (cf EDIT) if you have an idea why.

Comment: That’s because you call the actionOne function every 3 seconds and just append whatever it returns to the HTML page. If you want it to overwrite previous data you need to set innerHTML to “” (empty string) before each call.

Comment: Ok, but as I clear my array logs and setProperty to empty I should not have a full array each call. It looks like two thread is processing with two var logs one empty and one where I push all my logs but could not clear it. I declare var logs =[] as a global variable at the beginning of the script.